# VB 6 Data Access Component installation on Windows 2012 Server

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install Visual basic 6.0 on windows 2012 server, it’s not installing, and if I remove data access components it’s installed successfully. But I am not installed data access component excel reference is missing.

Comment: DO you mean the VB6 IDE or a VB6 app? See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikosan/archive/2012/04/20/support-statement-for-visual-basic-6-0-on-windows-8.aspx

Comment: Sounds confusing.  VB 6.0 does not install any version of Excel so there would never be any "Excel reference" (some type library?).  Maybe you can be clearer about the issue.  Is this really asking about the obsolete Excel Desktop ODBC Driver?  The Jet Excel IISAM should already be present, installed as part of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This was also my problem.

I solved it by unchecking the Data Access Components installation in Visual Studio 6 and, instead of that, by installing the`AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` which is the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

Link to download here: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

From the MS Documentation:

> The Office System Drivers are only supported under certain scenarios,
>   including:
>
> - Desktop applications which read from and write to various files    formats including Microsoft Office Access, Microsoft Office Excel and 
>     text files.
> - To transfer data between supported file formats and a database    repository, such as SQL Server.

Important note: sadly, in my existing applications i had to change my MDAC references, and the connection strings like described below (for new applications this isn't an issue):

> If you are an application developer using OLEDB, set the Provider
>   argument of the ConnectionString property to
>   “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0”